# issues with raw MySQL queries in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

I am using Django raw sql queries for fetching data from database using joins and alias names 
**My query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   A.entity_id AS entity_id,
   A.email AS email,
   A.catquizid AS style_quiz_score,
   A.catquizquesans AS style_quiz_answer,
   A.created_at AS date_joined,
   A.is_active AS is_active,
   B.attribute_id AS attribute_id,
   B.value AS info
FROM
   customer_entity AS A INNER JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS B
   ON A.entity_id=B.entity_id WHERE B.attribute_id LIMIT 2
```

I am fetching the results like this:

```
row = cursor.fetchall()
```

When I return a `HttpResponse` row it display the result which is correct but if I return `HttpResponse(row['entity_id'])` then it display the error `Sorry, an error occurred.`

So please tell me how i can access the array `row` using his alias names.

Answer (score 2):

**from here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/**

By default, the Python DB API will return results without their field names, which means you end up with a list of values, rather than a dict. At a small performance cost, you can return results as a dict by using something like this:

```
def dictfetchall(cursor):
    "Returns all rows from a cursor as a dict"
    desc = cursor.description
    return [
        dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]
```

Here is an example of the difference between the two:

```
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT id, parent_id from test LIMIT 2");
>>> cursor.fetchall()
((54360982L, None), (54360880L, None))

>>> cursor.execute("SELECT id, parent_id from test LIMIT 2");
>>> dictfetchall(cursor)
[{'parent_id': None, 'id': 54360982L}, {'parent_id': None, 'id': 54360880L}]
```